# Can functions have multiple inputs?

Tags: functions

Now bear with me here, I'm not the best at math. I'm just trying to find out something that I never really learned. I was wondering, can a function have multiple inputs such as this one below?

$$f(x,y) = x \cdot y$$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Short answer:** Yes.

**Long answer:** Yes, but using the [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), you can consider multiple inputs as being a single input, where the single input is an [ordered pair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair). So with your example, $f(x,y)=xy$, you can either consider it as a bivariate function with two inputs, $x$ and $y$; or as a univariate function with a single input, the pair $(x,y)$.

Comment: Another way to see all functions as functions of one variable is Currying https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying

Comment: but do functions normally only have 1 input in calculus?

Comment: @lmn32: In univariate calculus, yes. In multivariate calculus, no.